# buildConfigField method not found in separate gradle file

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build-tools

**I have:**

1. Some flavors ("en", "es" etc)
2. A `myData.properties` file for each flavor in `project/config/{FLAVOR_NAME}`
3. Self-made `gradle` file with method to add fields to `BuildConfig.java` file.

**My goal:**

Call my method for currently selected flavor while build and create fields in `BuildConfig.java`

**My problem:**

I can pass flavors name to my method to get correct file for flavor, but `buildConfigField` method is not found in that case.

Also I could pass a `ApplicationVariant variant` variable to my method and call `variant.buildConfigField` method in my custom gradle file, but I can't get `variant` variable in `productFlavors` section of `build.gradle(module app)`. I can get it outside while looping through `applicationVariants.all { variant ->`, but so it iterates over all flavors and if I cant miss `myData.properties` for some flavor. I want to be able to build only flavors for which I have file and throw my custom exception for which that do not have this file.

**TL/DR:**

How to call `buildConfigField` in custom `gradle` file or how to get `ApplicationVariant variant` in `productFlavors`

---

My custom `gradle.file`:

**marketSkusCreator.gradle**

```
ext {
    fillArrays = { variant ->
        def pathToFileWithData = "config/" + variant.productFlavors[0].name + "/marketSkus.properties"

        if (rootProject.file(pathToFileWithData).exists()) {
            def marketSkusPropertiesFile = rootProject.file(pathToFileWithData);
            def properties = new Properties()
            properties.load(new FileInputStream(marketSkusPropertiesFile))

            //buildConfigField - method not found, so I cant pass only flavor name as string to fillArrays method
            //buildConfigField('String[]', 'OLD_SKUS', properties.get("marketSkusOld"))
            variant.buildConfigField('String[]', 'OLD_SKUS', properties.get("marketSkusOld"))
            variant.buildConfigField('String[]', 'VER_2_SKUS', properties.get("marketSkusVer2"))
            variant.buildConfigField('String[]', 'INAPP_SKUS', properties.get("marketSkusInapp"))
        } else {
            logger.lifecycle('pathToFileWithData: {}', pathToFileWithData)
            throw new GradleException("You need to have marketSkus.properties file in root of project with " +
                    "marketSkusOld," +
                    "marketSkusVer2," +
                    " variables to build project")
        }
    }
}
```

**build.gradle(module app)**

```
import com.android.build.gradle.api.ApplicationVariant

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply from: '../marketSkusCreator.gradle'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'

    productFlavors {
        es {
            fillArrays(curVariant) //how to get it - {curVariant} (type: ApplicationVariant)
        }

        en {
            fillArrays(curVariant) //how to get it - {curVariant} (type: ApplicationVariant)
        }
    }

    //this works, but I do not want to call method for each flavor during each build
    //applicationVariants.all {ApplicationVariant variant ->
    //    fillArrays(variant)
    //}
}
```

---

Same question in russian: [buildConfigField метод не виден в отдельном gradle файле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/693700/17609)